# how to remove all slashes from all path aliases

Tags: 7, path-aliases

After I import data to my site, the url aliases  have `/` at the end, when I visit that Url alias I faced with `page not found`, I tried to edit one of  them manually and when I removed the slash from end I could see that node correctly, my question is how can I remove all slashes `/` from all aliases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution is using `Views Bulk Operation`, create a view  and with using  `run arbitrary Php option` in VBO try to remove all `/` from aliases,

something like ( I didn't test this )

```
  $entity->path['alias'] = rtrim($entity->path['alias'] ,'/');
```

and another and faster solution is using [MYSQL TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) in order to  update in database
go to phpadmin my admin ( or mysql command line ) and  run below command

```
 UPDATE `url_alias` SET `alias`= TRIM(TRAILING '/' FROM `alias` )
```